# Can I place unit test result validation in the @After method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing a Unit test for the behavior of a method, and want to **try to reduce my code duplication** - I'm about to double the test cases again, and the file is getting a bit hard to look at.

If anyone's *really* interested, [the code is here](https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit-Bleeding/blob/riking/additem/src/test/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/inventory/InventoryAddTest.java) (warning to the future - link may not be permanent).

Right now, I do the following, repeated several times in slightly different ways:

```
@Test
public void testAdd64OfMax64() {
    // Set up container
    TileEntityChest nmsinv = new TileEntityChest();
    Inventory container = new CraftInventory(nmsinv);
    // Call method
    HashMap<Integer,ItemStack> leftover = container.addItem(new ItemStack(Foo, 64));
    // Set up expected result
    ItemStack[] expected = empty.clone();
    expected[0] = new ItemStack(Foo, 64);
    // Verify result
    assertThat(container.getContents(), is(expected));
    assertThat(leftover, is(Collections.EMPTY_MAP));
}
```

(Note: assertThat comes from `org.hamcrest.Matchers`.)

I know that I can put the "Set up container" and cloning the empty array into a @Before method.

My question is, can I put the `assertThat` method into an @After method **and have the test still fail** (when it should fail)?

Answer (score 3):

No. The `After` method should be used to release external resources after a test run. Also, note that it is guaranteed to run even if your `Test` method throws an exception which may not be desirable in your case.

Also, think about the people who will have to maintain your code in the future. You are violating the [PLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Least_Astonishment), by validating the results of your tests in the `After` method. Nobody expects that!

It would be better if you created a helper method e.g. `checkResults` which was called at the end of each of your `Test` methods to validate your results.

Comment: Oh, a `checkResults` method.. didn't think about that. Yeah, that sounds like what I want.